# Multiple discrete values in MATLAB graph

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have some data that I'd like to plot on a graph in MATLAB.
the data is discrete - specifically these are 2 series of data against a single vector.
I could easily do it in excel like this:

[image]

but I want to do it in matlab. I tried to use the stem function, but the 2 series values are shown on the same bar (and I want them side by side, like the excel does):

[image]

In addition, I would like to show on the x bar only the values I'm interested in (in my case: 2,4,8,16,32). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to draw a bar graph, there is a dedicated built-in function, named [**`bar()`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html), for that purpose.

You can do it using:

```
N = [2 4 8 16 32];
val1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
val2 = [3; 5; 6; 12; 17];
bar([N],[val2,val1]);   % If you want val1 to appear first then use bar([N],[val1,val2]);
```

which gives the following desired result:

[image: output]